# What is the use of attention_layer_size?

Tags: tensorflow, seq2seq

I am following [a code](https://gist.github.com/ilblackdragon/c92066d9d38b236a21d5a7b729a10f12) to learn the seq2seq API. I am unable to figure out what the `attention_layer_size` parameter is for and why is it set to `num_units/2`